# ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:686)

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I did setup Apache and PHP, when i tried to connect through PDO i get this message
i am using oracle 10g enterprise management.

```
OCISessionBegin: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified  (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:686)
```

This is how i tried to make oracle connection

```
$tns = "
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = COD3R-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = opera)
    )
  )
       ";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns, 'customsearch', 'babaji');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: In `CONNECT_DATA` you have to add the `SID` and `SERVER` you can leave `SERVICE_NAME`

Comment: Also, add `putenv("NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1");` Above `$tns`

Comment: @Daan
Can you please update the answer, i mean if possible please show the changes i have to do in answer so i copy paste it. sorry i am not good in this syntax thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
putenv("NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1");
$tns = "
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = COD3R-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = I_DONT_KNOW_YOUR_SID)
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    )
  )
       ";
try {
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns, 'customsearch', 'babaji');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
```

}